# Error creating bean defined in class path resource [rabbit-context.xml] from dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I upgraded spring amqp & rabbit version from 1.7 to 2.2.8 Release version. The build deployment fails with this error from a dependent service jar. How can this be resolved.

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
```

````
Error creating bean with name 'amqpAdmin' defined in class path resource [rabbit-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy.<init>(I)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)```
````

Comment: You need to show your `rabbit-context.xml`. But you probably have an old version of spring-retry on the classpath. It should be 1.2.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an old version of spring-retry on the classpath - that constructor was added in 1.1.4.

You should be using 1.2.5 or 1.3.0.

Comment: I updated spring retry to 1.3.0. The deployment shows no error, but on server page I see this error :
{
status: 500,
code: 500,
message: "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageProperties.setCorrelationId([B)V",
request_url: "/v1/",
request_method: "GET",
more_info_url: "http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=home"
}

Comment: Edit the question to show the full stack trace - at some point between 1.7.x and 2.2.x the `correlationId` was changed from `byte[]` to `String` - since you are jumping over the interim releases, you missed the deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for failure is many dependent jars are still on older version of the spring rabbit lib.